# Car stereo wiring for illumination

Tags: toyota, wiring, audio, electronics

A friend gave me the Toyota PZ071 stereo head unit. He installed a different set in his car and the original head unit he gave to me. Unfortunately, the installer left the original connector harness in the car thus I got the bare head unit without the harness.

I dismantled the unit and trace the connections to solder out the required wires. This is easier and cheaper than looking around for the original harness.

What bother me is, there are two functional pins for Illumination functions. Normally a single Illumination wire will be connected to the car light switch so that it lights up the head unit control panel at night. While all I have seen got only one illumination lead, this head unit has two, ILL+B and ILL-.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how these wires are used during the actual installation? Internet search not helpful.